# Agreement statistics for confusion matrix with nominal categories

Tags: r, cohens-kappa, confusion-matrix, agreement-statistics

I have a decision support system that recommends Treatments (`T1` to `T8`) to patients, where `T`'s are nominal (i.e. no ordering or rating between them). I compare the system recommendations with the recorded treatments in a confusion matrix, where the columns list computer recommendations and the rows list recorded treatments:

```
cmg <- matrix(c(1639, 116, 49, 35, 138, 0, 0, 236,
                 150, 274, 27, 21,  28, 0, 0,  73,
                  22,  24, 58,  9,  94, 0, 0,  30,
                  33,  27, 31, 21, 146, 0, 0,  49,
                  14,   9,  5,  1,  49, 0, 0,  22,
                   1,   0,  1,  1,   7, 0, 0,   6,
                  11,   0,  0,  1,  14, 0, 0,  21,
                 201,  11,  8,  5,  49, 0, 0, 253), 
              ncol=8,dimnames = rep(list(c("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5", "T6","T7", "T8")),2))
```

Based on `cmg`, I need to provide some **agreement statistics** and report how much the system agrees with recorded treatments.

I checked this [link](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/agree.htm#recs), which suggests finding [overall and specific agreements](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/raw.htm) for nominal data. Here, specific agreements are calculated by collapsing the matrix to a binary confusion matrix [2*2] for each `Ti`. Also, they suggest calculating Cohen's Kappa both for `cmg` and for each collapsed matrix separately. 
I do these as below:

```
require(psych)
# Overall agreement
overall_agg <- sum(diag(cmg))/sum(cmg)

# Overall Cohen's Kappa for cmg
unweighted_kappa <- cohen.kappa( cmg, n.obs=sum(cmg) )

# initialise containers
spec_agr_guideline <- list()        
collapsed_mat_guideline <- list() 
unweighted_kappa_psych <- list()

# loop through all treatments    
for (i in seq(1,nrow(cmg)) ) {
  # Specific agreements
  spec_agr_guideline [i] <- 2*cmg[i,i] / (sum(cmg[i,]) + sum (cmg[,i]) )
  # Collapsed positive agreement confusion matrices per treatment
  collapsed_mat_guideline[[i]] <- matrix(c(cmg[i,i],             sum(cmg[i,])-cmg[i,i],
                                         sum(cmg[,i])-cmg[i,i],  sum(cmg)-sum(cmg[i,])-sum(cmg[,i])+cmg[i,i]), 
                                       ncol=2)
  # Calculate unweighted Cohen's Kappa per collapsed (binary) confusion amtrix
  unweighted_kappa_psych[[i]] <- cohen.kappa( collapsed_mat_guideline[[i]], n.obs=sum(collapsed_mat_guideline[[i]]) )
}
```

**Questions:**

**1)** Do I report the magnitudes of the Cohen's Kappas, or their p-values or something else? How can I interpret the Kappa results?E.g. for `cmg`, I get the output below:

```
unweighted_kappa
Cohen Kappa and Weighted Kappa correlation coefficients and confidence boundaries 
                 lower estimate upper
unweighted kappa  0.34     0.36  0.38
```

**2)** It is said that the usefulness of the Kappa values are [open to debate](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/kappa.htm). Are there any other agreement stats that I need to report in my (nominal data) case? For instance, in the same link, they suggest [Stuart-Maxwell, McNemar tests](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/mcnemar.htm#stuart), etc..

Comment: I am not so sure if I understood properly, can we consider the decision support system as a prediction model?. If so obvious statistics will be Sensitivities and Specificities and all can be summarised into a VUS (Volume under the ROC surface). But if you are more interested into classification rather than predictions a whole set of different statistics are applicable.

Comment: The contex is not (ML) classification, and the outputs are not probabilities so AUROC would not be applicable. In terms of specificity and sensitivity, can you explain how they can be applied in this (multinomial outcome) case? I have only calculated these for binary outcomes.

Comment: As you have stated you have just one contingency table and hence AUROC are not applicable that is true. In this multinomial case the terms like sensitivity and specificity should be avoided. You can simply term them correct prediction: = $P(Y=i|D=i)$, where $i$ corresponse to surgery,...,. $Y$ is the Top recorded plan( Predicted)  and $D$ is the Recorded plan (Known).

Comment: Hence is just dividing the numbers in the diagonal by sum of all entries in the corresponding column.